# Removing extra characters from a discord rest api response object

Tags: discord

There are extra characters coming up in my response text. This sets off json.load as it can't load data outside `{}`, any ideas of why are there extra characters?

Here is my code:

```
def request_access_token(client_id: str, client_secret: str, code: str, redirect_uri: str) -> dict:
    host = "discord.com"
    path = "/api/oauth2/token"
    port = 443

    data = f"client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}"
    request = f"POST {path} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: {host}\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: {len(data)}\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n{data}"

    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with socket.create_connection((host, port)) as sock:
        with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host) as ssock:
            ssock.sendall(request.encode())

            response = b""
            while True:
                data = ssock.recv(1024)
                if not data:
                    break
                response += data

    response_text = response.decode().split("\r\n\r\n", 1)[-1]
    response_json = json.loads(response_text)
    return response_json
```

Response before decoding:

> b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Sun, 16 Apr 2023 16:06:53 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nConnection: close\r\ncache-control: no-store\r\npragma: no-cache\r\nset-cookie: __dcfduid=b421a9dadc7011ed94ad4ed281080386; Expires=Fri, 14-Apr-2028 16:06:53 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/\r\nstrict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload\r\nVia: 1.1 google\r\nAlt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400\r\nCF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC\r\nReport-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v3?s=2LeJWDtGm%2BjTJBMQ6rJw9ffUCn4Ua4u%2BmZrK9BCPFrFkMNh7uWAP6ASY6T7nBjpp22R8KE6nlrgvoRST0KHJdsMzxrQc%2BzYKk%2BUmkPhtoulfrer416t6j60uQYe4"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}\r\nNEL: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}\r\nX-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\nSet-Cookie: __sdcfduid=b421a9dadc7011ed94ad4ed281080386744252200dcc44954da600ffa75b6335e70760259186266b878e3c3d8f5e8306; Expires=Fri, 14-Apr-2028 16:06:53 GMT; Max-Age=157680000; Secure; HttpOnly; Path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: __cfruid=821c9cf5d74a21b5bad2e221f7b3f91630cba0d1-1681661213; path=/; domain=.discord.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None\r\nServer: cloudflare\r\nCF-RAY: 7b8dad97a8f676c3-LHR\r\n\r\nde\r\n{"access_token": "the token", "expires_in": 604800, "refresh_token": "the token", "scope": "applications.commands.permissions.update email identify guilds", "token_type": "Bearer"}\r\n0\r\n\r\n'

Response after decoding:

> de
> {"access_token": "the token", "expires_in": 604800, "refresh_token": "the token", "scope": "email applications.commands.permissions.update guilds identify", "token_type": "Bearer"}
> 0

I have tried just removing them from the string which works but I don't trust it, and I'm expecting no extra characters.

Is there a way to remove what I assume is the length of chunks and the signal to end the chunks from a response object discord rest api?

Comment: Have you tried `response.content.decode('utf-8').splitlines()` instead of `response.decode().split("\r\n\r\n", 1)[-1]`?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `sockets` instead of a higher level protocol with the `requests` module?

Comment: The `0` is expected per HTTP standard and `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`. As Mark said you should use a proper HTTP library such as `requests` instead of you trying yourself to reimplement an HTTP client and not following standards properly. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding